# Insert cross-reference to numbered header in MSWord

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

We have headings like:

**1.2.3 Test Login Functionality**

I want to insert across reference to this heading which includes both the text AND number, but it seems Word only lets me do one or the other. Is it possible to do what I want in a single insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried everything and it looks like the answer is no, which is strange as there are so many other switches for reference fields.

The best solution would be to include two STYLEREF fields, one for the number and one for the text.